# WPF Databinding ContextMenuItem's CommandParameter to TreeViewItem's DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu, command-pattern

I am using the Command pattern with (among other things) a context menu on a TreeViewItem, which uses HierarchicalDataTemplates.  The MainWindowViewModel (a static resource for the Window) has properties that expose singleton objects that in turn have properties that represent the commands.  I am able to execute the command just fine, but some of the commands need to pass the TreeViewItem's DataContext as the CommandParameter.

Here's a specific example:
One node of the tree has the ItemsSource bound to an ObservableCollection of individual AnalysisMain objects.  Each of the resulting subnodes has a ContextMenu (with a DataContext bound to the AnalysisController) which has (among others) a Remove MenuItem.  The Remove MenuItem's Command property is bound to the CommandRemove command on the AnalysisController singleton object (and it executes just fine).  But this also requires the CommandParameter to be bound to the AnalysisMain object that serves as the DataContext for the subnodes in the tree.  I have tried using RelativeSource with the AncestorType set to TreeViewItem and the Path set to DataContext:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmAnalysis:AnalysisMain}">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Analysis\Icon_Analysis_Main_16_Normal.png" Margin="0,0,2,0" Width="16"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TreeViewTitle}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{StaticResource mainWindowViewModel}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding Path=AnalysisController.CommandRemove}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=4}, Path=DataContext}">
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Without the AncestorLevel set, when I open the ContextMenu, I get the following in the Output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem', AncestorLevel='4''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

I have tried several values for the AncestorLevel to no avail.

From examining the Visual Tree in Christian Mosers WPF Inspector, I don't see the context menu in the visual tree. Although the TreeViewItem shows the DataContext object.  I just need a way to "navigate" to it in order to bind to it.

---

As an alternative, I have tried leaving the ContextMenu DataContext alone and setting the Command Binding's Source to point back to the AnalysisController.  This also works for executing the command, but I am not able to bind to the TreeViewItem's DataContext for the CommandParameter:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainWindowViewModel}, Path=AnalysisController.CommandRemove}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext}">
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

I have also tried just using CommandParameter="{Binding}", which also doesn't work.  (In both cases, I just get null sent as the parameter.  No warning / error is written to the Output window.) EDIT: For anyone else with this problem, the second option was doomed from the beginning, because I mistakenly put in Source={RelativeSource Self}, which would refer to the MenuItem and not the TreeViewItem.  However, changing this with AncestorType / AncestorLevel makes no difference.

Comment: I may be wrong about the exact bug related to `CommandParameter` binding, in fact the parameter is null inside `CanExecute` (meaning Binding does not work) but inside `Execute` callback, the parameter is passed OK. For the code I posted before, you can try looking in the Output window to see if there is any error notified there.

Comment: I checked (overrode the CanExecute to always return true), and the parameter is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu
        DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

And on your `MenuItem` do a `RelativeSource` to `ContextMenu` then use `PlacementTarget.DataContext` as your binding to your `CommandParameter`

Comment: Do I need to use Setter versus just setting the property?  (I am familiar with Setters only when used with Triggers.)  Here is what I ended up with: (on ContextMenu) DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" and on the MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"

Comment: @Tim You can directly use the Property, I just had a snippet that uses Styles

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but this did not work for me.  Does what I posted look like it would work?  I also tried it with a style (closer to your original answer), but this also did not work.

Comment: No, you want the DataContext for the ContextMenu to set to the `TreeViewItem` and do `RelativeSource AncestorType` then on the `MenuItem` you do the `PlacementTarget.DataContext`

Comment: Sorry, not the best at XAML databinding when it gets complicated.  Which part is wrong?  I have this:

Comment: Can you try using `Snoop` and check for the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` when you do that binding.

Comment: I am using WPF Inspector, and Snoop seems to function the same.  In both programs, the ContextMenu does not show up in the Visual Tree.

Comment: Just found the Ctrl+Shft combo with a ContextMenu open.  Both the ContextMenu and the MenuItem have a DataContext of null.

Comment: What's the DataContext of TexttBlock

Comment: (Please don't hate me).  Just figured out the problem.  The property for the command was using Remove() as the Action instead of just Remove.  So the parameter was being stripped out at the property before the method was actually being called.  I went back to your code for the ContextMenu DataContext and that works with the CommandParameter={Binding} on the MenuItems.  As such, I am marking your response as the answer.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear and can't figure out everything unless I see all code. Thanks :)